# Joining the same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, alias

I'm trying to list some data in a table. The data comes from a database, I have 3 tables in my DB.

I'm trying to join those 3 three tables in a SQL-statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cases
LEFT JOIN users ON cases.fk_supporter = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN users ON cases.fk_creator = users.user_id
```

The `fk_supporter` is a foreign key to a user and so is the `fk_creator` to, but not the same user. How to  do this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need unique alias for same tables in the join

```
SELECT * FROM cases c
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON c.fk_supporter = u1.user_id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON c.fk_creator = u2.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to give **ALIAS** name to table

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cases c
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON c.fk_supporter = u1.user_id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON c.fk_creator = u2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ALIAS` for your `users` table:

```
SELECT * FROM cases
LEFT JOIN users supporter ON cases.fk_supporter = supporter.user_id
LEFT JOIN users creator ON cases.fk_creator = creator.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you would have something other than LEFT JOIN, try INNER JOIN with Alias name as @Saharsh and @Abhik mentioned- like:

```
SELECT * FROM cases C
INNER JOIN users U1 ON C.fk_supporter = U1.user_id
INNER JOIN users U2 ON C.fk_creator = U2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it working like this:

```
SELECT 
supporter.usr AS supporter_usr, 
supporter.user_id as support_id,
creator.usr AS creator_usr, 
creator.user_id as creator_id,
cases.* FROM cases


LEFT JOIN users AS supporter 
ON supporter.user_id = cases.fk_supporter

LEFT JOIN users AS creator 
ON creator.user_id = cases.fk_creator
```